# Problem using the `geom_col` in plotnine with Linux (Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS) and Windows

Tags: python, plotnine

When I try to run the following reproducible example using `plotnine` I get an error:

```
import pandas as pd
from plotnine import (
      ggplot, aes, 
      geom_col
)
from plotnine.data import mtcars


df = (mtcars.
loc[:, ["name", "disp"]].
drop_duplicates(subset="name"))

(ggplot(data=df,
        mapping=aes(x="name", y="disp")) +
 geom_col())
```

This is the complete error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\ANACON~1\Lib\site-packages\plotnine\ggplot.py", line 114, in __repr__
    figure = self.draw(show=True)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\ANACON~1\Lib\site-packages\plotnine\ggplot.py", line 224, in draw
    self._build()
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\ANACON~1\Lib\site-packages\plotnine\ggplot.py", line 336, in _build
    layers.compute_position(layout)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\ANACON~1\Lib\site-packages\plotnine\layer.py", line 479, in compute_position
    l.compute_position(layout)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\ANACON~1\Lib\site-packages\plotnine\layer.py", line 345, in compute_position
    data = self.position.compute_layer(data, params, layout)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\ANACON~1\Lib\site-packages\plotnine\positions\position.py", line 79, in compute_layer
    return groupby_apply(data, "PANEL", fn)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\ANACON~1\Lib\site-packages\plotnine\utils.py", line 599, in groupby_apply
    lst.append(func(d, *args, **kwargs))
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\ANACON~1\Lib\site-packages\plotnine\positions\position.py", line 77, in fn
    return cls.compute_panel(pdata, scales, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\ANACON~1\Lib\site-packages\plotnine\positions\position_stack.py", line 103, in compute_panel
    nl_trans = get_non_linear_trans(scales.y)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\ANACON~1\Lib\site-packages\plotnine\positions\position_stack.py", line 97, in get_non_linear_trans
    if _is_non_linear_trans(sc.trans):
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\ANACON~1\Lib\site-packages\plotnine\positions\position_stack.py", line 87, in _is_non_linear_trans
    trans.dataspace_is_numerical and tname not in linear_transforms
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'identity_trans' object has no attribute 'dataspace_is_numerical'
```

My session info is the following:

```
-----
pandas              2.1.4
plotnine            0.12.2
session_info        1.0.0
-----
Python 3.11.6 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Oct  3 2023, 10:29:11) [MSC v.1935 64 bit (AMD64)]
Windows-10-10.0.22621-SP0
-----
Session information updated at 2023-12-13 13:38
```

I think the problem is with Windows taking into account that at least in Linux Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS you will get some warnings related to the `mizani` module but it works fine and it will generate the plot.

However in Linux Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS if you change the variables that corresponds to each axis, `x="disp", y="name"`, you will get a strange plot using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
from plotnine import (
      ggplot, aes, 
      geom_col
)
from plotnine.data import mtcars


df = (mtcars.
loc[:, ["name", "disp"]].
drop_duplicates(subset="name"))

(ggplot(data=df,
        mapping=aes(x="disp", y="name")) +
 geom_col())
```

[image]

Where my session info in the case of Linux is the following:

```
-----
pandas              2.1.1
plotnine            0.12.1
session_info        1.0.0
-----
Python 3.10.9 (main, Mar  1 2023, 18:23:06) [GCC 11.2.0]
Linux-6.2.0-37-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.35
-----
Session information updated at 2023-12-13 13:53
```

Anyone knows what will be a possible solution for Windows and how you can fix the plot in Linux?

Comment: Install the latest version of plotnine  (v0.12.4) and it will automatically pickup the right version of mizani.

Comment: Adding issue to plotnine repository: https://github.com/has2k1/plotnine/issues/741

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until plotnine learns to infer the orientation of the plot based on the types mapped to the aesthetics, the solution is to use map the discrete column to the `x` aesthetic then use `coord_flip` to flip the axes.

```py
import pandas as pd
from plotnine import ggplot, aes, geom_col, coord_flip
from plotnine.data import mtcars

(ggplot(mtcars, aes(x="name", y="disp"))
 + geom_col()
 + coord_flip()
)
```